# snmp not responding under heavy network load

Tags: linux, monitoring, snmp, snmpd

We have a group of servers with high usage of cpu and network (with 10 Gb bandwidth). Under this circumstances `snmpwalk` requests to this servers got timeout. So we can't monitor them.

The question is how to help snmp service to respond to requests?

I already tried to increase snmpd process' priority with `renice` command but nothing changed

Comment: How many object do you get with snmpwalk ? Try to limit to the minimum

Comment: good advice! I will try it and let you know

Comment: @Dom I walked on single oid but I didn't get any result, same as walking on large oid!

Comment: Maybe try in TCP (SNMPv3) if possible : the UDP packets maybe lost if the network link is full

Comment: @dom using TCP makes response time faster, but not fast enough! I think we must add another network for monitoring purposes, because current network is fully saturated!

Comment: To monitor a device you should never use `snmpwalk`. Please use `snmpget` or other commands which only query the necessary objects.